# Split string in C by inserting a null character

Tags: c, split, segmentation-fault

I am trying to split a string in C by inserting a null character and I keep getting the error `segmentation fault (core dumped).` The line `p[0] = '\0'`; keeps causing this issue. How would I avoid this and split the string by inserting a Null character at the space on `"say hello?`"

```
char *sentence = "say hello";
printf("You typed: %s\n", sentence);

char *allbutfirst = sentence + 1;
printf("Everythign but first letter is %s\n", allbutfirst);

char *secondpart = sentence + 5;
printf("Skipping the first 5 letters, the rest is %s\n", secondpart);

// strchr finds the first occurence of a letter
char *p = strchr(sentence, ' ');
printf("Everythign starting at first space is %s\n", p);

// turn the space into a '\0' "null character", effectively splitting
// the string into two parts.
p[0] = '\0'; // assign using array notation
// now, sentence ends where the space used to be
// and (p+1) points to the rest of the text.
printf("First word is %s\n", sentence);
printf("Rest of sentence is %s\n", p + 1);
```

Comment: You should declare `sentence` as an array: `char sentence[] = "say hello"`.  As it is, you are trying to write to an area of read only memory.

Comment: Check the return of `strchr`. It returns `NULL` in case of not finding the token or in case of error. Also, `*p` is a char pointer returning the position of the token, change it to `p = '\0'` instead of `p[0] = '\0'`

Comment: @phyloflash the `p[0] = '\0';` is correct, provided that `strchr` did not return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because

```
char *sentence = "say hello";
```

should be actually declared as

```
const char *sentence = "say hello";
```

String literals, the ones in the code you write in quotes like `"say hello"`, are
not mutable, meaning they are read-only, you cannot alter their contents.

```
char *p = strchr(sentence, ' ');
```

If the empty space is found, `p` is still pointing to read-only memory, thus

```
p[0] = '\0';
```

ends with a segfault. Also `strchr` may return `NULL` if the empty space is
**not** found and when `p` is `NULL`, this also leads to a segfault.

How to fix it? Use an array of `char` instead and initialize it with the string,
also check for the return value of `strchr`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char sentence[] = "say hello";
    printf("You typed: %s\n", sentence);

    char *allbutfirst = sentence + 1;
    printf("Everythign but first letter is %s\n", allbutfirst);

    char *secondpart = sentence + 5;
    printf("Skipping the first 5 letters, the rest is %s\n", secondpart);

    // strchr finds the first occurence of a letter
    char *p = strchr(sentence, ' ');
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Empty space not found\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Everythign starting at first space is %s\n", p);

    // turn the space into a '\0' "null character", effectively splitting
    // the string into two parts.
    p[0] = '\0'; // assign using array notation
    // now, sentence ends where the space used to be
    // and (p+1) points to the rest of the text.
    printf("First word is %s\n", sentence);
    printf("Rest of sentence is %s\n", p + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or, `char *sentence = (char[]){ "say hello" };`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've never seen that in the wild. Who uses that?

Comment: It is a *compound literal* initializer. Handy `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin well thank you for showing me that, I learn a new thing every day :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the only thing I don't like about that, is that (presumably)  `sizeof sentence / sizeof *sentence` won't give you the number of objects. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, `sentence` is just *a pointer* initialized to point to the character array containing the string `"say hello"`, so `sizeof sentence` is just `sizeof (a pointer)`;. The compound literal is generally used to initialized structs, etc.., it's not purposefully intended to initialize strings (though it can be used that way).